# why there is a space left at right side of output?How can i fill the space using bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, containers, navbar

[why there is a space at the end of the output? How can i fill the space using bootstrap 4?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkBBh.png)

```css
.navbar-custom {
     background-color:rgb(128 128 128 / 18%);
     height:48px;
}
 .close{
     margin-bottom: 40px;
}
 h2{
     margin-top: 35px;
     margin-left: 34px;
}
/* .logo1{
     margin-bottom: 120px;
}
 */
 .container-fluid {
     max-width: 100%;
     padding-right:0;
     padding-left:0;
     margin-right:0;
     margin-left:0 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
            <!-- Brand/logo -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <div class="mt-0 ">
                    <img src="logo.png" class="logo1" alt="logo" style="width:50px;"></div>
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>

        </nav>
    </div>
    <h2>Do you have Fever above 101.4?</h2>
    <div class="mx-auto mt-5" style="width:150px">
        <img src="fever.png" class="logo1" alt="logo" style="width:200px;">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row row-cols-1">
        <div class="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-5">Yes,I do</button></div>
        <div class="col"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-2">No, I don't</button></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fill the space using bootstrap 4?I am working on this project and experienced a problem that instead of using container-fluid , the items are not completely filling the space on right side.

Comment: Can you add your `head` and your JavaScript if any? If I copy the HTML that you sent and add JQuery and Bootstrap the buttons go all the way to the edge of the screen for me. The Navigation bar goes all the way to the edge of the `container-fluid`, if you want it to go all the way to the edge of the screen you need to take it outside the container. For example, in the bootstrap site they use a `header` tag.

Answer (score 0):

`margin-right:-15px` and `margin-left:-15px` in your row class cause it. set them zero.

```
.no-margin
{
  margin-right:0 !important;
  margin-left:0 !important;
}
```

and in your html, add no-margin;

```
 <div class="row row-cols-1 no-margin">
    ........
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the default `row` style of bootstrap will set `margin-left: -15px` and `margin-right: -15px` so it will overflow the container and show the horizontal scrollbar

For you to use a bootstrap `row` make sure that it's inside of the `container` or `container-fluid` class so the styling will work properly

Remember for bootstrap to use the grid/column, you need to make sure the structure is `container` then child `row` then child `col`

Updated the snippet by moving the content inside the `container-fluid` class

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: rgb(128 128 128 / 18%);
  height: 48px;
}

.close {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-left: 34px;
}


/* .logo1{
     margin-bottom: 120px;
}
 */

.container-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
      <!-- Brand/logo -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <div class="mt-0 ">
          <img src="logo.png" class="logo1" alt="logo" style="width:50px;"></div>
      </a>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>

    </nav>
    <h2>Do you have Fever above 101.4?</h2>
    <div class="mx-auto mt-5" style="width:150px">
      <img src="fever.png" class="logo1" alt="logo" style="width:200px;">
    </div>
    <div class="row row-cols-1">
      <div class="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-5">Yes,I do</button></div>
      <div class="col"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-2">No, I don't</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```